# Запись и вывод числа с плавающей точкой. Ассемблер

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться как записать в переменную Х число с плавающей точкой и вывести его в MessageBox. Заранее спасибо!

```
    .486                ;используетс¤ набор команд i80486
.model flat, STDCALL    ;модель FLAT, соглашение STDCALL
option casemap:none ;различать ѕ–ќѕ»—Ќџ? и строчные
include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
.data               ;сегмент данных

X SDWORD 110.110010b    ;??

;=======переменные функции MessageBox =================
MsgBoxTitle BYTE "Заголовок MessageBox",0
MsgBoxText  BYTE 128 dup(?),0
;=======строка спецификации формата====================
format1 db "Значение X в 10-й системе X=", "%d","d",0Dh,0Ah,
"Значение X в 16-й сиcтеме X=","%x","h",0Dh,0Ah,0
;======================================================

.code                   ;сегмент кода
start:              ;метка начала основной программы

invoke wsprintf, addr MsgBoxText,addr format1, X, X
invoke MessageBox, 0, ADDR MsgBoxText, ADDR MsgBoxTitle, MB_OK

invoke ExitProcess, 0         ;API функция завершения процесса
end start               ;конец основной программы
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вы делаете. Число с плавающей точкой, как бы оно не задавалось,  не может быть корректно сконвертировано по спецификациям `%d` и `%x`.

Comment: а как тогда его можно вывести? я пробовал другие, не получается. может вообще там другой тип данных нужно задавать?